# How to find ISD code from ISO 3166 code?

Tags: java, android, iso, iso-3166

I want to show ISO 3166 country code and its ISD code in list

Like:

```
ind +91
irq +964
ita +39
```

With the help of `java.util.Locale` I have got all ISO 3166 country codes but now I want ISD codes of every country.

Comment: If you want only ISD code then hard code it as shown in answer two because library is very huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google's [libphonenumber](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com) and use its [`PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getCountryCodeForRegion()`](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#getCountryCodeForRegion%28java.lang.String%29). It takes an ISO 3166 code as a String as an argument.

Note that this utility class also has a [`.getSupportedRegions()`](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#getSupportedRegions%28%29) method.

Comment: How should I use getCountryCodeForRegion method? I am trying like this PhoneNumberUtil.getCountryCodeForRegion("in"); but its saying PhoneNumberUtill cannot be resolved..

Comment: Well, you need to add the libphonenumber library to your project first

Comment: And have you imported the class?

Comment: yes import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;                      after clean build now its saying Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getCountryCodeForRegion(String) from the type PhoneNumberUtil

Comment: Oops... See edit. But a quick look at the javadoc would have solved that for you

Answer (score 1):

I also have same requirement in my application, I couldn't find any api regarding this. So what I did, I create a array in res and put all the ISD codes in it and then use Local for all details. List of code is as follow

```
<string-array name="countryArray">
    <item>AC,247</item>
    <item>AD,376</item>
    <item>AE,971</item>
    <item>AF,93</item>
    <item>AG,1</item>
    <item>AI,1</item>
    <item>AL,355</item>
    <item>AM,374</item>
    <item>AN,599</item>
    <item>AO,244</item>
    <item>AQ,672</item>
    <item>AR,54</item>
    <item>AS,1</item>
    <item>AT,43</item>
    <item>AU,61</item>
    <item>AW,297</item>
    <item>AZ,994</item>
    <item>BA,387</item>
    <item>BB,1</item>
    <item>BD,880</item>
    <item>BE,32</item>
    <item>BF,226</item>
    <item>BG,359</item>
    <item>BH,973</item>
    <item>BI,257</item>
    <item>BJ,229</item>
    <item>BL,590</item>
    <item>BM,1</item>
    <item>BN,673</item>
    <item>BO,591</item>
    <item>BR,55</item>
    <item>BS,1</item>
    <item>BT,975</item>
    <item>BW,267</item>
    <item>BY,375</item>
    <item>BZ,501</item>
    <item>CA,1</item>
    <item>CD,243</item>
    <item>CF,236</item>
    <item>CG,242</item>
    <item>CH,41</item>
    <item>CI,225</item>
    <item>CK,682</item>
    <item>CL,56</item>
    <item>CM,237</item>
    <item>CN,86</item>
    <item>CO,57</item>
    <item>CR,506</item>
    <item>CU,53</item>
    <item>CV,238</item>
    <item>CY,357</item>
    <item>CZ,420</item>
    <item>DE,49</item>
    <item>DJ,253</item>
    <item>DK,45</item>
    <item>DM,1</item>
    <item>DO,1</item>
    <item>DZ,213</item>
    <item>EC,593</item>
    <item>EE,372</item>
    <item>EG,20</item>
    <item>ER,291</item>
    <item>ES,34</item>
    <item>ET,251</item>
    <item>FI,358</item>
    <item>FJ,679</item>
    <item>FK,500</item>
    <item>FM,691</item>
    <item>FO,298</item>
    <item>FR,33</item>
    <item>GA,241</item>
    <item>GB,44</item>
    <item>GD,1</item>
    <item>DE,995</item>
    <item>GF,594</item>
    <item>GH,233</item>
    <item>GI,350</item>
    <item>GL,299</item>
    <item>GM,220</item>
    <item>GN,224</item>
    <item>GP,590</item>
    <item>GQ,240</item>
    <item>GR,30</item>
    <item>GT,502</item>
    <item>GU,1</item>
    <item>GW,245</item>
    <item>GY,592</item>
    <item>HK,852</item>
    <item>HN,504</item>
    <item>HR,385</item>
    <item>HT,509</item>
    <item>HU,36</item>
    <item>ID,62</item>
    <item>IE,353</item>
    <item>IL,972</item>
    <item>IN,91</item>
    <item>IO,246</item>
    <item>IQ,964</item>
    <item>IR,98</item>
    <item>IS,354</item>
    <item>IT,39</item>
    <item>JA,81</item>
    <item>JM,1</item>
    <item>JO,962</item>
    <item>JP,81</item>
    <item>KE,254</item>
    <item>KG,996</item>
    <item>KH,855</item>
    <item>KI,686</item>
    <item>KM,269</item>
    <item>KN,1</item>
    <item>KP,850</item>
    <item>KR,82</item>
    <item>KW,965</item>
    <item>KY,1</item>
    <item>KZ,7</item>
    <item>LA,856</item>
    <item>LB,961</item>
    <item>LC,1</item>
    <item>LI,423</item>
    <item>LK,94</item>
    <item>LR,231</item>
    <item>LS,266</item>
    <item>LT,370</item>
    <item>LU,352</item>
    <item>LV,371</item>
    <item>LY,218</item>
    <item>MA,212</item>
    <item>MC,377</item>
    <item>MD,373</item>
    <item>ME,382</item>
    <item>MG,261</item>
    <item>MH,692</item>
    <item>MK,389</item>
    <item>ML,223</item>
    <item>MM,95</item>
    <item>MN,976</item>
    <item>MO,853</item>
    <item>MP,1</item>
    <item>MQ,596</item>
    <item>MR,222</item>
    <item>MS,1</item>
    <item>MT,356</item>
    <item>MU,230</item>
    <item>MV,960</item>
    <item>MW,265</item>
    <item>MX,52</item>
    <item>MY,60</item>
    <item>MZ,258</item>
    <item>NA,264</item>
    <item>NC,687</item>
    <item>NE,227</item>
    <item>NG,234</item>
    <item>NI,505</item>
    <item>NL,31</item>
    <item>NO,47</item>
    <item>NP,977</item>
    <item>NR,674</item>
    <item>NU,683</item>
    <item>NZ,64</item>
    <item>OM,968</item>
    <item>PA,507</item>
    <item>PE,51</item>
    <item>PF,689</item>
    <item>PG,675</item>
    <item>PH,63</item>
    <item>PK,92</item>
    <item>PL,48</item>
    <item>PM,508</item>
    <item>PR,1</item>
    <item>PS,970</item>
    <item>PT,351</item>
    <item>PW,680</item>
    <item>PY,595</item>
    <item>QA,974</item>
    <item>RE,262</item>
    <item>RO,40</item>
    <item>RS,381</item>
    <item>RU,7</item>
    <item>RW,250</item>
    <item>SA,966</item>
    <item>SB,677</item>
    <item>SC,248</item>
    <item>SD,249</item>
    <item>SE,46</item>
    <item>SG,65</item>
    <item>SH,290</item>
    <item>SI,386</item>
    <item>SK,421</item>
    <item>SL,232</item>
    <item>SM,378</item>
    <item>SN,221</item>
    <item>SO,252</item>
    <item>SR,597</item>
    <item>ST,239</item>
    <item>SV,503</item>
    <item>SX,1</item>
    <item>SY,963</item>
    <item>SZ,268</item>
    <item>TC,1</item>
    <item>TD,235</item>
    <item>TG,228</item>
    <item>TH,66</item>
    <item>TJ,992</item>
    <item>TK,690</item>
    <item>TM,993</item>
    <item>TN,216</item>
    <item>TO,676</item>
    <item>TR,90</item>
    <item>TT,1</item>
    <item>TV,688</item>
    <item>TW,886</item>
    <item>TZ,255</item>
    <item>UA,380</item>
    <item>UG,256</item>
    <item>UK,44</item>
    <item>US,1</item>
    <item>UY,598</item>
    <item>UZ,998</item>
    <item>VA,379</item>
    <item>VC,1</item>
    <item>VE,58</item>
    <item>VG,1</item>
    <item>VI,1</item>
    <item>VN,84</item>
    <item>VU,678</item>
    <item>WF,681</item>
    <item>WS,685</item>
    <item>XT,800</item>
    <item>YE,967</item>
    <item>ZA,27</item>
    <item>ZM,260</item>
    <item>ZW,263</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Well now you know of such an API ;) See my answer

Comment: how it will use if we don't konw  the ISO 3166 code of the country